# What is the use of the 'label' property in matplotlib box plots?

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, label, boxplot

I'm using box plots from matplotlib and tried to use the labels to assign colors to the box faces; using code that looked something like the following:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = {}
data['a'] = np.arange(12)+1
data['b'] = np.arange(14)+1
data['c'] = np.arange(8)+1

color_dict = {'trt_a':'red', 'trt_b':'blue', 'trt_c':'green'}
controls = ['trt_a', 'trt_b', 'trt_c']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

boxplot_dict = ax.boxplot([data[x] for x in ['a', 'b', 'c']], \
    positions = [1, 1.5, 2], labels = controls, \
    patch_artist = True, widths = 0.25)

for b in boxplot_dict['boxes']:
    lab = b.get_label()
    print("Label property of box ", i, " is ", lab)
    b.set_facecolor(color_dict[lab]) # <- This is what I would like to be able to do

ax.set_ylim([0,16])
plt.show()
```

I understand the use of `labels` as an input argument to name different boxplots.  However, I notice that the label property of the boxes, when accessed with the `get_label` method is not set to anything.

So what use is the label property (not the input argument)?

Answer (score 4):

The `labels` argument in `ax.boxplot()` sets the `xticklabels` of the axis, not the labels of the boxes objects (which would be used in e.g. `ax.legend()`).

So instead, you can access the labels you want from `ax.get_xticklabels`.  The relevant snippet to replace in your code is:

```
for b in boxplot_dict['boxes']:
    lab = ax.get_xticklabels()[i].get_text()
    print("Label property of box {0} is {1}".format(i, lab))
    b.set_facecolor(color_dict[lab]) 
    i += 1
```

The full code would be:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = {}
data['a'] = np.arange(12)+1
data['b'] = np.arange(14)+1
data['c'] = np.arange(8)+1

color_dict = {'trt_a':'orange', 'trt_b':'blue', 'trt_c':'green'}
controls = ['trt_a', 'trt_b', 'trt_c']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

boxplot_dict = ax.boxplot(
    [data[x] for x in ['a', 'b', 'c']],
    positions = [1, 1.5, 2],
    labels = controls, 
    patch_artist = True,
    widths = 0.25)

i=0
for b in boxplot_dict['boxes']:
    lab = ax.get_xticklabels()[i].get_text()
    print("Label property of box {0} is {1}".format(i, lab))
    b.set_facecolor(color_dict[lab]) 
    i += 1

ax.set_ylim([0,16])
plt.show()
```

[image: Boxplot Example]

---

Alternate example, setting the `label` property of the box objects

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = {}
data['a'] = np.arange(12)+1
data['b'] = np.arange(14)+1
data['c'] = np.arange(8)+1

color_dict = {'trt_a':'orange', 'trt_b':'blue', 'trt_c':'green'}
controls = ['trt_a', 'trt_b', 'trt_c']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

boxplot_dict = ax.boxplot(
    [data[x] for x in ['a', 'b', 'c']],
    positions = [1, 1.5, 2],
    labels = controls, 
    # patch_artist = True,  # Legend isn't working with patch objects.. 
    widths = 0.25)

i=0
for b in boxplot_dict['boxes']:
    lab = ax.get_xticklabels()[i].get_text()
    print("Label property of box {0} is {1}".format(i, lab))
    b.set_color(color_dict[lab])
    b.set_label(lab)
    i += 1

ax.set_ylim([0,16])
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I understand the 'labels' argument for setting the xtick labels.  The answer you posted is a nice work around to link in the color setting functionality.  

However, as per my initial question, I'm interested in the `labels` property of the `boxes` key that's output by calls to `matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot`.  It can be accessed with the `get_labels` method.

Comment: As far as I know, the labels property of any `Artist` object is primarily useful only when auto-generating a legend (http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_label).  For the 'boxes' objects that you're generating, these are not used and are just empty strings.  However, If you want, you can set the labels explicitly and use them in generation of a legend. I've edited the example above to show this.